# Ошибка vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [29] Rate limit reached

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Хотел попробовать сделать программу для автоматической смены статуса аккаунта в вк. Во время запуска программы выдает ошибку:

> **vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [29] Rate limit reached**

Вот код:

```
#импорт библиотек
import vk_api


def startStatus(): # функция смены статуса
    bot = vk_api.VkApi(token='token_id') # Инициализируем сессию бота ВКонтакте через токен
    info = "info" # Текст статуса
    vk = bot.get_api()
    vk.status.set(text = info) # Выполняем смену статуса

startStatus()
```

Ошибка связана со строкой `vk.status.set(text = info)`. Если ее изменить на `vk.status.set(info)`, то появляется эта ошибка:

> **TypeError: **call**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given**

Не могу понять в чем проблема. В документации ничего не нашел на эту тему

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```py
def startStatus(): # функция смены статуса
    bot = vk_api.VkApi(token='token_id') # Инициализируем сессию бота ВКонтакте через токен
    info = "info" # Текст статуса
    vk = bot.get_api()
    bot.method('status.set', {'text' : info}) # Выполняем смену статуса
```

Если ошибка с `Rate limit reached` остаётся, то проблема в количестве вызовов в сутки, [подробнее тут](https://github.com/python273/vk_api/issues/411).

Comment: Прошу прощения, опечатка вышла.

Comment: Обновил ответ :)